# Cannot select label when labelling images anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

It's no longer possible to select or modify labels when labelling images in Google's AutoML (we haven't migrated to Vertex AI).
I have setup a new Object-Detection dataset for this example, containing one image and two labels: 'door' and 'window':

When I enter the labelling view, I can draw bounding boxes, but once drawn, it's no longer possible to change the label or remove the bounding box again. Neither element is clickable:
[image: Google AutoML Image Labelling]

The problem is not contained to this google-cloud project, we have tried different ones. We tried different browsers (Latest chrome and firefox) and also reset the browser cache in both browsers. As mentioned, I also already tried setting up a brand new dataset.

Any hints on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Google is pushing their followup-product "Vertex AI" over AutoML Vision.

Even though AutoML is not officially cancelled, once we migrated the datasets to the new Vertex AI platform (as decribed by [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/migrating-to-vertex-ai)), labelling was possible again, with a only slightly changed UI.